# find reciprocal best hits for a query

Tags: awk, sed, grep, biopython, blast

I have a blast output and would like to obtain the reciprocal best hit i.e.,finding best hit by making sure that a query is a reference's best hit and vice versa based on values from columns 3 and 11 (for a threshold of column 3 >40 and column 11 < 2e-04.

```
MnCG00500.1 Ma.15G248500.1  27.78   180 60  5   9   188 1   110 6e-04   41.2
MnCG00510.1 Ma.15G003800.1  87.88   33  4   0   6   38  3   35  2e-13   60.1
MnCG00510.1 Ma.10G208900.1  84.85   33  5   0   6   38  3   35  2e-12   57.0
MnCG00510.1 Ma.17G173700.1  84.85   33  5   0   6   38  3   35  9e-12   55.5
MnCG00280.1 Ma.11G114700.1  97.17   106 3   0   22  127 22  127 8e-65   210
MnCG00280.1 Ma.05G074900.1  98.18   55  1   0   420 474 11  65  3e-29   111
MnCG00280.1 Ma.20G242300.1  80.36   56  11  0   419 474 95  150 3e-22   95.1
MnCG00890.1 Ma.05G094500.1  89.55   67  7   0   321 387 4   70  1e-34   125
MnCG00890.1 Ma.01G201500.1  91.07   56  5   0   332 387 1   56  3e-28   107
```

I tried using a similar one liner based on column 12 alone and tried modifying to suit my conditions

```
 awk '{
       a[$1]="0";b[$1]="";c[$2]="0";d[$2]="";
       if (e[$1,$2]==0) 
         e[$1,$2]=$12; 
       else {
         score=e[$1,$2]+$12; 
         e[$1,$2]=score
       }
     }
     END{
       for (i in a) 
         for (j in e) {
           split(j,f,SUBSEP); 
           if (f[1]==i && e[j]>a[i]) {
             a[i]=e[j];b[i]=f[2]
           }
         }; 
         for (i in c) for (j in e) {
           split(j,f,SUBSEP); 
           if (f[2]==i && e[j]>c[i]) {
            c[i]=e[j];d[i]=f[1]
         }
       }; 
       for (i in b) 
         if (b[i] in d && d[b[i]]==i) 
           print i"\t"b[i]"\t"a[i]"\t"c[b[i]]
     }' result.blast
```

But does not work.

In the end I would need something like

```
MnCG00500.1, Ma.15G248500.1, MnCG00500.1, no_match  
MnCG00510.1, Ma.15G003800.1, match  
MnCG00510.1, Ma.10G208900.1, match  
MnCG00510.1, Ma.17G173700.1, match  
MnCG00280.1, Ma.11G114700.1, match  
MnCG00280.1, Ma.05G074900.1, match  
MnCG00280.1, Ma.20G242300.1, match  
MnCG00890.1, Ma.05G094500.1,MnCG00890.1, no match   
MnCG00890.1, Ma.01G201500.1, match
```

Comment: this condition is not satisfied for any rows `$3>40 && $11>2e-04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get RBH from the output of a single blast run.
The best scoring hits from the target db are collected then blasted back against the query db. 
If the best hits from this second blast match the query sequences from the first blast then the query and target sequences are "reciprocal best hits"

The most you can do with just one blast output is to get the id from the target db to blast back against the query db.

hope that helps.

also smaller E(xpect) values are better, so you would want column_11 < 2e-04

Comment: Or use higher bitscore which is a better behaved number (like likely to have any floating point rounding issues).

Answer (score 0):

Only the best hit in a output file:

```
blastx -query myFile.fasta -db myDB -evalue 0.00001 -num_alignments 1 -outfmt "7 qseqid sseqid"  | uniq > myResult.txt
```